# relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_ZN6GVars33GUIE' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a c++ shared library on Ubuntu 14.04 with the following command:

> g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libPTAM.so.1 -o libPTAM.so.1.0.1
>   GLWindow2.o GLWindowMenu.o VideoSource_Linux_DV.o System.o
>   ATANCamera.o KeyFrame.o MapPoint.o Map.o SmallBlurryImage.o
>   ShiTomasi.o HomographyInit.o MapMaker.o Bundle.o PatchFinder.o
>   Relocaliser.o MiniPatch.o MapViewer.o ARDriver.o EyeGame.o Tracker.o
>   -L MY_CUSTOM_LINK_PATH -lGVars3 -lcvd -lGL -llapack -lc

However it encounters the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: GLWindow2.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against
>   `_ZN6GVars33GUIE' can not be used when making a shared object;
>   recompile with -fPIC 
>   GLWindow2.o: error adding symbols: Bad value 
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>  Makefile:73: recipe for
>   target 'libPTAM' failed make: *** [libPTAM] Error 1

As command above shows, I do use -fPIC option to compile.
Could anyone help me to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: The library that provides `GLWindow2`, which appears to be [`PTAM`](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/ptam/html/classGLWindow2.html), needs to be built with `-fPIC`, too. Add `-fPIC` to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`, and then recompile PTAM. You may be able to configure with `--enable-shared` to achieve it if PTAM is an Autotools project.

Comment: @jww Yes you are right, thank you!